# Why does a LIKE query in Access not return any records?

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledbcommand

Is there any reason why

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [_Items] LIKE '*SPI*'
```

does not return any records with `OleDbAdapter.Fill(DataSet)` or `OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()`?

When I run the same SQL in MS Access directly, it returns the expected records. Also, in the same code, if I change the SQL to

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

all records are returned.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to run an SQL query "in MS Access directly?"

Comment: In MS Access, you can create a query, in SQL mode. That is what I meant to type the query in Access directly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change your `*` to `%` as `%` is the wildcard search when using OLE DB.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [_Items] LIKE '%SPI%'
```

Comment: This answer fails to communicate that `*` is correct in certain situations, though `%` is correct in other situations.  My access 2010 database prefers `*`.  See @onedaywhen's answer below.

Answer (score 35):

Try changing `LIKE` to `ALIKE` and your wildcard characters from `*` to `%`.

The Access Database Engine (Jet, ACE, whatever) has two [ANSI Query Modes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx) which each use different wildcard characters for `LIKE`:

- ANSI-89 Query Mode uses `*`
- ANSI-92 Query Mode uses `%`

OLE DB always uses ANSI-92 Query Mode.
DAO always uses ANSI-89 Query Mode.
The Access UI can be set to use one or the other.

However, when using `ALIKE` keyword the wildcard character is always `%` regardless of ANSI Query Mode.

Consider a business rule that states a data element must consist of exactly eight numeric characters. Say I implemented the rule as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MyStuff 
(
 ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
 CHECK (ID NOT LIKE '%[!0-9]%')
);
```

It is inevitable that I would use `%` as the wildcard character because Access's `CHAR` data type and `CHECK` constraints can only be created in ANSI-92 Query Mode.

However, someone could access the database using DAO, which always uses ANS-89 Query Mode, and the `%` character would be considered a literal rather than a 'special' character, and the following code could be executed:

```
INSERT INTO MyStuff (ID) VALUES ('%[!0-9]%');
```

the insert would succeed and my data integrity would be shot :(

The same could be said by using `LIKE` and `*` in a Validation Rule created in ANSI-89 Query Mode and someone who connects using ADO, which always uses ANSI-92 Query Mode, and INSERTs a `*` character where a `*` character ought not to be.

As far as I know, there is no way of mandating which ANSI Query Mode is used to access one's Access database. Therefore, I think that all SQL should be coded to behave consistently regardless of ANSI Query Mode chosen by the user.

Note it is not too difficult to code for both using `LIKE` with the above example e.g.

```
CHECK (
       ID NOT LIKE '%[!0-9]%'
       AND ID NOT LIKE '*[!0-9]*'
      )
```

...or indeed avoid wildcards completely e.g.

```
CHECK (ID LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

However, using `ALIKE` will result in less verbose code i.e. easier for the human reader and therefore easier to maintain.

Also, when the time comes to port to a SQL product that is compliant with SQL Standards, `ALIKE` ports well too i.e. transforming the `ALIKE` keyword to `LIKE` is all that is required. When parsing a given SQL predicate, it is far, far easier to locate the one `LIKE` keyword in than it is to find all the multiple instances of the `*` character in text literals. Remember that "portable" does not mean "code will run 'as is'"; rather, it is a measure of how easy it is to move code between platforms (and bear in mind that moving between versions of the same product is a port e.g. Jet 4.0 to ACE is a port because user level security no longer functions, `DECIMAL` values sort differently, etc).

Comment: I assume `ALIKE` is short for `ANSI LIKE`. I don't see it as of any use except for people who are foreigners to Access. It means you end up writing non-portable SQL, but really, what matters is your data interface method. If you are a refugee from outside Access and knee-jerk must use % as your wildcard, then all you have to do is insure that you always use data access methods that will use ANSI 92 mode. That will result in portable SQL and with no proprietary kludges like `ALIKE`. Really, if you're going to use ALIKE, you might as well just use * -- both are non-portable.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "all you have to do is insure that you always use data access methods that will use ANSI 92 mode" -- rather, one would have to ensure that *all* users only use ANSI-92 Query Mode but how would one do that? As far as I know it is not possible. Therefore, you need to handle both ANSI Query Modes or expose your clients to data integrity issues. Also, `ALIKE` is highly portable, far more portable than using `LIKE` + `*`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: ALIKE is supported by other database engines? I didn't know that -- I thought it was Jet/ACE-specific. Just from Googling for a minute, I find no evidence of ALIKE being supported by any other database engine.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I don't understand your point about "ensure that *all* users only use ANSI-92 Query Mode". If you're building an application, you've got full control on that. If you have a Jet/ACE back end that you'd like to restrict to that mode, you set that property for that database. Now, that won't have any effect whatsoever on access to that database from DAO, but it will mean that if somebody opens it in Access, it will use SQL 92 mode. I don't know that ODBC supports it in any scenario, but I could be wrong. So, I don't get your point.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "If you're building an application, you've got full control on that... Now, that won't have any effect whatsoever on access to that database from DAO... I don't know that ODBC supports it..." -- you've kind of made the point for me: you don't have any control over the ANSI Query Mode your SQL code will be executed in! If you think you do then you are kidding yourself :)

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "I find no evidence of ALIKE being supported by any other database engine" -- See my update: "Remember that "portable" does not mean "code will run 'as is'"; rather, it is a measure of how easy it is to move code between platforms..." Transforming `ALIKE` to `LIKE` is one of the easiest ports you can hope for :)

Comment: You mean it's much easier than transforming SQL with "*" as wildcard to using "%" as wildcard? Looks like a plain search and replace in both cases to me, so I can't see why one would prefer one over the other.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: No, I mean it's much easier to transform `ALIKE` to `LIKE` than it is to transform `*` to `%` -- consider that you may be parsing a concatenated string, handling `*`, `CHR(42)` and `CHR$(42)`, and that the `*` character or `42` ascii code could be stored in a table! But it's a minor issue compared with the ANSI Query Mode neutrality one.

Answer (score 5):

Try converting your wildcard chars (*) to %

This should sort the issue out.

Answer (score 0):

Jeez, this works!
Thanks a lot.

I just had to replace `not like criteria` to `not alike criteria`.

I'm sharing my "story" to help others find this post easier and save them from a two hours search.

Although I've linked the Excel 95-97 xls files to the Access 2010 database, and ran `create table` and `insert into` queries to import all data into a database, for some strange reason, the select query couldn't find the strings I've typed.

I tried `not like "something"` and `not like "%something%"` with no success - simply didn't work.

L