# How to use LIKE operator with wildcards in query in MS-Access using c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, wildcard

I am using MS Access database in my C# app, where I need to pass parameterized-like query. I came around various documents saying we can use "*" or "?" as wildcards. But when i try to add it to my query it throws exception.

Actually MSAccess uses like in this format ... LIKE "*United*" {here double quotes are mandatory.} But as a string in my C# code i cant create " in runtime. If i use " in my string more than once a red wave appears.

So I need a way to use query with wildcard support.

My string is this

```
SELECT student.roll_no, student.s_name, fee.fee_date, (fee.adm_fee+fee.mon_fee+fee.lib_fee+fee.exm_fee) AS fee, class.c_name
FROM class
INNER JOIN (fee INNER JOIN student ON fee.s_id = student.s_id) ON (fee.c_id = class.c_id) AND (class.c_id = student.c_id)
WHERE student.s_name Like ""\""*" + name + "\"*";
```

I want my like condition in my command text as `... WHERE student.s_name Like "*xyx*"`

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but in your code, you can put `"` in a string in C# by adding a backslash before it.  `"\""` is a string consisting of just `"`.

Comment: Can you post your code with the exceptions which are thrown getting at which line?

Comment: I think it needs to be more like this - `Like \"*"+name+"*\"";`

Comment: Which wildcards you use depends on which data interface you are using to query your Access/Jet/ACE database. If you're using DAO or ODBC, yes, you use the traditional Access `*`/`?` wildcards. But if you're using OLEDB, you use SQL 92 wildcards, `%`/`_`. If you want to write SQL with partial matches that both Access in SQL 89 mode and SQL 92 mode can understand, you can use the proprietary ALIKE operator ("ANSI LIKE"), which use the ANSI 92 wildcards.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166907/ms-access-sql-any-reason-why-like-does-not-work/5170214#5170214).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may just have the formatting in your string incorrect (of course, that's assuming you're getting an SQL Exception, since you didn't mention any details about the Exception :))

```
string commandtext =@"SELECT student.roll_no, student.s_name, fee.fee_date, (fee.adm_fee+fee.mon_fee+fee.lib_fee+fee.exm_fee) AS fee, class.c_name FROM class INNER JOIN (fee INNER JOIN student ON fee.s_id = student.s_id) ON (fee.c_id = class.c_id) AND (class.c_id = student.c_id) WHERE student.s_name Like \"*"+name+"*\"";
```