# MS Access Contains query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How to write contain query for msaccess database

My table have column value **' CHOPE PARMA TERA 101'**

my search keyword in **PARMA**.

How can I write contain query to retrieve the record ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Query in MS Access:

```
select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like '* PARMA *'
```

For standard SQL, it would be like `'% PARMA %'`

Note that the above statement would not find 'PARMA', 'CHOPE PARMA', or CHOPE PARMAHAM 101', or 
any value with that contains PARMA; to do so just remove the spaces in the search string, e.g. `'*PARMA*'`

```
select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like '*PARMA*'
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work
SELECT *
FROM groups
WHERE (Orgin LIKE '* PARMA *')

only the below is working, SELECT *
FROM groups
WHERE (Orgin LIKE 'CHOPE PARMA TERA 101')   is there way to look only for PARMA

Comment: Does it work with `ALike` instead of `Like`?: `SELECT * FROM groups WHERE Orgin Alike '%PARMA%'`

Comment: Had to look that up. Never heard of it. The answer appears to be maybe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166907/ms-access-sql-any-reason-why-like-does-not-work

Comment: um just read your coment, try % instead of * with like first. According to the other link it depends on what mode you are in. I've no idea, haven't done access since about 93..

Answer (score 10):

Are you asking about using the Like condition?
If so, there's more info [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php)

MS Access: LIKE Condition (using wildcards) in Access 2003/XP/2000/97

The LIKE condition allows you to use wildcards in the where clause of an SQL statement in in Access 2003/XP/2000/97. This allows you to perform pattern matching. The LIKE condition can be used in any valid SQL statement - select, insert, update, or delete.

The patterns that you can choose from are:

```
* allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)
? allows you to match on a single character
# allows you to match on a single numeric digit
```

For Example

```
Like 'b*'   would return all values that start with b
Like '*b*'  would return all values that contain b
Like '*b'   would return all values that end with b
Like 'b?'   would return all values that start with b and are 2 characters in length
Like 'b#'   would return all values that start with b and are 2 characters in length
where the second character is a number
```

Comment: Is there any way to check a string starting with question mark (?) , FIELD Like '*?*' not working