# DataSet coming as Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, web-applications

I have a method called searchDB that search the database according to keyword typed by user.

I am storing the search results in DataSet. This method search in only one column.

```
        public DataSet searchDB(string identifier)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT [identifier] FROM [Category3] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '" + identifier + "*'";
                //string sql = "SELECT [identifier] FROM [Category3]";

                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "identifier");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            else
                return dataSet;
        }
```

The variable "identifier" gets value from the `textbox`.
Suppose, when i pass "windows" as value for variable, it should return 1 row. 
But when i put breakpoint, it is hitting the if condition

```
if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    return null;
}
```

and returning 0 rows.

Can anyone point out my mistake.

Comment: use this: string sql = "SELECT [identifier] FROM [Category3] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%" + identifier + "%'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the SQL LIKE wrong (unless your `identifier` column really ends with an asterisk):

```
SELECT [identifier] FROM [Category3] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '" + identifier + "*'
```

Like uses the `%` character for wildcard, instead of `*`, so try:

```
SELECT [identifier] FROM [Category3] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '" + identifier + "%'
```

---

**Edit**: I didn't see that the question concerns MS Access, but the answer holds true still. See the following SO question: [Why does a LIKE query in Access not return any records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166907/ms-access-sql-any-reason-why-like-does-not-work)

> The Access Database Engine (Jet, ACE, whatever) has two ANSI Query Modes which each use different wildcard > characters for LIKE:
>
> - ANSI-89 Query Mode uses *
> - ANSI-92 Query Mode uses %

Comment: But i am using ms access, i thought it uses *

Comment: It works actually... Umm I thought access uses * instead of %

Comment: Hm yes, I checked on MS Access, they indeed seem to be using `*`. But if it works for you, then all is fine.

Comment: see my comment below your question, i answered you.

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE filter should use % instead of * like here:

```
 LIKE '" + identifier + "%'
```