# Clear with query in database access 97 mdb c #

Tags: c#

I created a button with link code to the 97 access database and a delete query, but when I run the code, nothing is deleted in the database

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+ textBox1.Text;            
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM cartellini WHERE id_car LIKE '??2021????'", connect);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted", "Deleted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        connect.Close();            
    }
```

how can i solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Please show us the table definition of table `cartellini` and especially the `id_car` column, and a few rows of representative example data.

Comment: I posted the picture of the tables and rows

Answer (score 1):

Try using following wildcards: `%` instead of `*` and `_` instead of `?`

```
WHERE id_car LIKE '__2021____'
```

See also [Why does a LIKE query in Access not return any records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166907/why-does-a-like-query-in-access-not-return-any-records)

Comment: Oops, in that case I will remove my comment. It will be useful to add such relevant background info into your answer, if possible with a reference link if you can find one.